# Dynamically create excel file and download autmatically

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "http://csharp.net-informations.com";

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp-Excel.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
```

here is my C# button code. i just want to do this excel file download automatiacally on button click. this code generate excel file only.And how to add download code. i dont know. Example we download anything in google chrome then click the item start download. and bottom of the browser download file show. how to do this,, Please help me
thanks in
Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code below you know the excel file path, where you are saving the excel file

```
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp-Excel.xls"
```

Now you know that you have created the excel file and save on the server on location (~/csharp-Excel.xls)
Create an instance of the object that generates Excel files

```
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/csharp-Excel.xls");
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
    string Outgoingfile = "FileName.xlsx";
    if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Outgoingfile);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();

        }
     else
        {
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
        }
```